# Why Inner Join on table where is no compatible records - takes too long?

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-spanner

I have Google Cloud Spanner database and I have SQL query where do next:

```
select
table_one.member_id,
table_one.owner_id
from table_one
inner join table_two
on table_two.id IN (...)
and ...
and ...
and ...
and ...
limit 20
offset 0
```

If table_two has compatible records where id IN (...), then request completes within 1 sec, that is okay, but table_two doesn't have compatible records - request completes within 1 minute.

How to speed up it, so in two cases request completes within 1 second?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your query you set a limit to 20, that means if there are "compatible records" i.e. match, then the query stops searching the database after 20 records are found, and the process is finished early, before the entire table has been traversed. But on the other hand if there are no "compatible records", the query will search the table to the very end, to confirm there no matches.
that's why it takes longer when there are no matches to return.
if you remove the limit, then it should take about the same time.

I would guess your query is slow because of `on table_two.id IN (...)`
instead of something like `on table_one.tabletwoId = table_two.id`

Comment: We do in such way (using IN instead of = ), because all our id fields are bytes and using IN in Google Spanner for bytes fields works faster

Comment: I understood your point, will reply you tomorrow

Comment: But it was done in such way, because we can use multiple values for table_two.id, because of that we use IN

Comment: Would you not be able to do Left Join table_two?

Comment: In such case we can receive null values from table_two that is inappropriate for us, this is not the behaviour which we expect.
To receive data from table_two is required we can't just receive null from there

Comment: Ok so my understanding is that you only want matches where there is a match between the two tables and that you only want one match per table_one record (owner_id, member_id) !? And I am assuming that table_one is the parent and table_two is the child table i.e. 1:N, table_one -< table_two 
With that assumption table_two always return many (or no) records per record in table_one 

Then this qyuery should do just that:

`SELECT table_one.owner_id, table_one.member_id FROM table_one
Inner join table_two on table_one.Id= table_two.FkId
Group by table_one.owner_id, table_one.member_id;`